# read a big binary file with mingw not working

Tags: c++, mingw, ifstream

I have a bug with mingw : I'm not able to read a big binary file (3.2 gb). My test code :

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

template<typename TYPE>
inline void read_binary_file(const fs::path filename, std::vector<TYPE>& result)
{

  std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary |std::ios::ate);

  file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
  size_t filesize = file.tellg();
  file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

  //size_t filesize = fs::file_size(filename); !!!!!<------------ BUG FOR mingw32 WITH gcc 10.2. Should be ok with gcc 10.3

  assert(filesize%sizeof(TYPE) == 0);
  result.resize(filesize/sizeof(TYPE));

  std::cout << "result size : " << result.size();

  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(result.data()), filesize);

  file.close();
}


int main()
{
  {
  fs::path path = "idx-position-Deces_Agit_FrHex_aPartir1979_Dom_aPartir2000_enCours-liens_age_tranche_age#age_quinquenal_0_100.dat";
  std::vector<uint32_t> result;

  read_binary_file<uint32_t>(path, result);

  for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << result[result.size()-3] << std::endl;
  std::cout << result[result.size()-2] << std::endl;
  std::cout << result[result.size()-1] << " " << uint32_t(-1) << std::endl;
  }


  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  {

    fs::path path = "idx-position-ALD_prevalence_MSA_2017_Communes-liens_maladie_ald#CIM10_ALD0516.dat";
    std::vector<uint32_t> result;

    read_binary_file<uint32_t>(path, result);

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
      std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << result[result.size()-3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << result[result.size()-2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << result[result.size()-1] << " " << uint32_t(-1) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have tried this code on 2 files (~3 mo and ~3 go) on two systems differents (gcc on linux and mingw on windows). On linux, I have this output :

```
result size : 8006943820
1
2
4
6
8
10
12
15
18

1174722779
1174722780
4294967295 4294967295



result size : 8554610
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

869037
869038
4294967295 4294967295
```

But on windows, for the 3 go file, the function std::ifstream::read seems to do nothing. My outputs :

```
filesize : 3202777528 
sizeof : 4 
filesize/sizeof : 800694382 
result size : 800694382
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 4294967295 


filesize : 3421844 
sizeof : 4 
filesize/sizeof : 855461 
result size : 8554610 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
869037 
869038 
4294967295 4294967295
```

The files are identical on linux and windows. My version of mingw is :

```
GNU Make 4.3 Built for Windows32 Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

and gcc is in version 10.2.

Comment: that's the version of gnu make, not mingw

Comment: Hum yes, it is the result of the command : ```mingw32-make.exe --version```.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char *>(result.data())` doesn't look like the proper way to do it...

Comment: `file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);` -> `file.seekg(0, file.end);` and `file.seekg(0, file.beg);` -> `file.seekg(0, file.beg);`?

Comment: The return type of `file.tellg();` is [`streampos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/streampos/), which is an [`fpos` type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fpos/), which can be converted to a **signed** integer type. So don't use `size_t`.

Comment: you are right, tellg() can send -1, so I will change the size_t. I am not sure to understand why reinterpret_cast<char *> is not the proper way : I want to read the file directly in the vector and I don't see other options (or the C way (char *) &result[0]).
For the tellg problem, the size found is the good one, so I don't think it's the root of the problem ...

Comment: Ah maybe ! But I ran mingw from ```C:/mys64/mingw64/bin/```, so I thought it was 64bits minGW ... It's not the case ?

Comment: and size_t give me value > 2 147 483 647 (filesize). It means that my application is in 64 bits ... Or I miss something ?

Comment: I read "Built for Windows32", so I was confused. Also, the missing endline after the `result.size()` print was a bit confusing.

Comment: Ah sorry, I copy from a virtual machine and the line return doesn't work with the copy (I had to do it at hand) I miss the first zero (edit now). The value  of result size is 800694382 so a 3.2 gigas vector at end. I have enough memory (4*32 gigas in ram)